# Python3 reading mixed text/binary data line-by-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, io, utf-16

I need to parse a file which has a UTF-16 text header and followed directly by binary data. To be able to read the binary data, I open the file in "rb" mode, then, for reading the header, wrap it into a io.TextIOWrapper().

The problem is that when I execute the `.readline()` method of the `TextIOWrapper` object, the wrapper reads ahead too far (even though I only requested a single line) and then runs into a UTF-16 decoding error when encountering the binary portion: A `UnicodeDecodeError` is raised.

However, I need proper parsing of the text data and cannot simply do a binary read first, then do a data.find(b"\n\0") because it's not guaranteed that this actually matches at an even offset (could be midway in-between characters). I would like to avoid doing UTF-16 parsing myself.

Is there an easy way to tell `TextIOWrapper` to not read ahead?

Comment: what kind of file is this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't use a `TextIOWrapper()` object because it'll read from the underlying buffer in larger blocks, not just in lines, so yes, it'll try to decode binary data past than first line. You *can't* prevent this.

For a single line of text using `\n` line delimiters, you really don't need to use `TextIOWrapper()`. Binary files still support line-by-line reading, where `file.readline()` will give you the binary data up to the next `\n` byte. Just open the file *as binary*, and read one line.

Valid UTF-16 data will *always* have an even length. But because UTF-16 comes in two flavours, big endian and little endian byte orders, you'll need to check how much data was read to see what byte order was used, in order to conditionally read a single byte that should be part of that first line of data. If UTF-16 little-endian was used, you are guaranteed to have read an odd number of bytes, as newlines are encoded to `0a 00` rather than `00 0a` and the `.readline()` call will have left the single `00` byte in the file stream. In that case, just read one more byte and add it to the first line data before decoding:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as binfile:
    firstline = binfile.readline()
    if len(firstline) % 2:
        # little-endian UTF-16, add one more byte
        firstline += binfile.read(1)
    text = firstline.decode('utf-16')

    # read binary data from the file
```

A demo with `io.BytesIO()` where we first write UTF-16 little-endian data (with the BOM to indicate the byte order for the decoder), with the text followed by two low-surrogate sequences that would cause a UTF-16 decoding error to stand for 'binary data', after which we read the text and data again:

```
>>> import io, codecs
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> binfile = io.BytesIO()
>>> utf16le_wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(binfile, encoding='utf-16-le', write_through=True)
>>> utf16le_wrapper.write('\ufeff')  # write the UTF-16 BOM manually, as the -le and -be variants won't include this
1
>>> utf16le_wrapper.write('The quick brown  jumps over the lazy \n')
40
>>> binfile.write(b'\xDF\xFF\xDF\xFF')  # binary data, guaranteed to not decode as UTF-16
4
>>> binfile.flush()  # flush and seek back to start to move to reading
>>> binfile.seek(0)
0
>>> firstline = binfile.readline()  # read that first line
>>> len(firstline) % 2              # confirm we read an odd number of bytes
1
>>> firstline += binfile.read(1)    # add the expected null byte
>>> pprint(firstline)               # peek at the UTF-16 data we read
(b'\xff\xfeT\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00q\x00u\x00i\x00c\x00k\x00 \x00b\x00r\x00o\x00'
 b'w\x00n\x00 \x00>\xd8\x8a\xdd \x00j\x00u\x00m\x00p\x00s\x00 \x00o\x00v\x00'
 b'e\x00r\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00l\x00a\x00z\x00y\x00 \x00=\xd8\x15\xdc'
 b'\n\x00')
>>> print(firstline.decode('utf-16'))  # bom included, so the decoder detects LE vs BE
The quick brown  jumps over the lazy 

>>> binfile.read()
b'\xdf\xff\xdf\xff'
```

Any alternative implementations that still can use `TextIOWrapper()` would require an intermediate wrapper to sit between the binary file and the `TextIOWrapper()` instance to prevent `TextIOWrapper()` to read too far, and this would get complex *fast* and would require the wrapper have knowledge of the codec used anyway. For a single line of text, that's just not worth the effort required.